# Active Profile in Windows Firewall

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, firewall

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server using Advanced Windows Firewall.

From my local PC I suddenly couldn't access the SQL Server database using a public IP. I logged on to the server and tried to access it via RDP which worked fine.

In my firewall I noticed that the private profile was marked active which was not the case of the domain or public profile.

How do I mark the public profile to be active? And how can this problem suddenly occur when it has worked for years?

Answer (score 0):

User,

I suppose you'd need to open/fwd the respective ports to access your sqlserver db from a public ip.

Try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Someone made the network itself private. Changing it to public resolved the issue